# How to show any div when a textbox is focused?

Tags: html, css

How can I show the `div.show` when `input.searchtext` is focused?

```
<div class="select-form-holder">
   <input class="searchtext" type="text" value="Find Friends, Movies, T.V shows Games" />
   <div class="show-on-focus">xyz</div>
   <input type="submit" class="btn-search" title="Search" />
</div>
```

Comment: USe jQuery: $('input.searchtext').focus(function() { $('div.show-on-focus').show();}, function() { $('div.show-on-focus').hide();});

Comment: well its working with css see the below answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
.searchtext:not(:focus) + .show-on-focus {
    display: none;
}
```

It reads: "If `searchtext` is *not `:focus`*ed, get the next sibling if it is `show-on-focus`".

Comment: very nice trick to improve the performance! Always had used javascript/jQuery for that :D

Answer (score 1):

Another way of accomplishing this using just an adjacent sibling selector.

```
.show-on-focus { display: none }
.searchtext:focus + .show-on-focus {
    display: block;
}
```

If you have multiple elements you want to hide, you can swap out the adjacent selector with a general sibling selector.

```
.show-on-focus { display: none }
.searchtext:focus ~ .show-on-focus {
    display: block;
}
```

Both are not as sexy as `:not`, but it'll have slightly better compatibility with older browsers.